# Angular 9 SSR with Firestore - meta tag is not loading dynamically

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore, server-side-rendering, universal

In angular 9 SSR, I am using Firestore to fetch the data. I am also updating the meta tags dynamically. When my JSON is in the local, the meta tags are updated and the tags are fetched in twitter card. But when I fetch data from Firestore and update my meta tags the twitter card is unable to fetch the updated meta tags. I found that the data fetch from Firestore is taking time after the page is initialized. So I am unable to change the meta tag dynamically in angular. Is there any way to solve this?[my twitter card fetch image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v6Hjq.png)